# How control Eclipse/maven snapshot cache?

Tags: eclipse, caching, maven

I have java project that depends from other java projects.
These projects are maven projects.
For manage maven I use

```
m2eclipse plugin.
```

Project is a web application running in Tomcat.

The problem, that after some time main project lost dependencies.
In Eclipse assembly they are present, but when I do debug in server (Tomcat) - the are not copied.

So I need do refresh of library projects, clean, update dependencies etc. After Eclipse deploy correct to Tomcat. But it always takes many time for all this clean, update procedures. Is it possible there may be some setting in Eclipse or maven plugin to always deploy last version of library projects? Maybe need set something about cache or snapshot version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use snapshot dependencies at all.

You can use the `<updatePolicy>` in settings.xml to control the interval when maven looks for updated versions. See http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-settings/settings.html

These are set per `<repository>`, allowed values are: "always", "daily" (default), "interval:XXX" (in minutes) or "never".